# how to sequentially assign two numbers in an array?

Tags: python, numpy

I try to assign two numbers diagonally to each other in the matrix according to certain procedures.
At first the first 1st number in the penultimate line of the line with the 2nd number in the last line, then the first number in the line up with the 2nd number in the penultimate line, etc..This sequence is shown in the example below. The matrix does not always have to be the same size.

Example

```
a=np.array([[11,12,13],
            [21,22,23],
            [31,32,33]])
```

required output:

```
21 32
11 22
11 33
22 33
12 23
```

or

```
a=np.array([[11,12,13,14],
            [21,22,23,24],
            [31,32,33,34],
            [41,42,43,44]])
```

required output:

```
31 42
21 32
21 43
32 43
11 22
11 33
11 44
22 33
22 44
12 23
12 34
23 34
13 24
```

It is possible?

Comment: So, you're reading all the diagonals of the array, and printing them in pairs.  Sure, that's possible, but you're going to do it by hand.  There's no single function to do it.  Two sets of nested loops, one going up the left edge, one going across the top.

Comment: "It is possible?" - No it's not. There's no way to make the 42 appear out of nowhere.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change the matrix, it's already fixed

Comment: Still isn't. There's no logic that explains `21 42`, and no logic explaining `11 22` appearing twice.

Comment: 21 and 42 corrected to 43, and 11 22 are numbers on the main diagonal

Comment: Why does `11 22` appear **twice**, though?

Comment: because I don't pay attention to what I'm writing and the other one is called there, corrected

Comment: Why is `22 33` not there?

Comment: it should be right now

Answer (score 0):

Here's an iterative solution, assuming a square matrix.  Modifying this for non-square matrices shouldn't be hard.

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([[11,12,13,14],
            [21,22,23,24],
            [31,32,33,34],
            [41,42,43,44]])

w,h = a.shape
for y0 in range(1,h):
    y = h-y0-1
    for x in range(h-y-1):
        print( a[y+x,x], a[y+x+1,x+1] )

for x in range(1,w-1):
    for y in range(w-x-1):
        print( a[y,x+y], a[y+1,x+y+1] )
```